# Does there exists an analytic function from $D$ to $D$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|<1\}$. Which of the following are correct?

1. There exists holomorphic function such that $f:D\rightarrow D$ with $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=2$.
2. There exists holomorphic function such that $f:D\rightarrow D$ with $f(3/4)=3/4$ and $f'(2/3)=3/4$.
3. There exists holomorphic function such that $f:D\rightarrow D$ with $f(3/4)=-3/4$ and $f'(3/4)=-3/4$.
4. There exists holomorphic function such that $f:D\rightarrow D$ with $f(1/2)=-1/2$ and $f'(1/4)=1$.

Using Schwartz Pick lemma we can prove or disprove for (1) and (3). But how to prove or disprove (2) and (4). I hope for this case i cannot use Schwartz lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Find automorphisms of $D$ that map $\frac 34\mapsto 0$ and $0\mapsto \frac 34$, respectively. From these and $f$ construct a holomorphic $g\colon D\to D$ with $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=???$. Similarly for 4.

Comment: $T(z)=\frac{(3/4)-z}{1-(3/4)z}$, this is the automorphism from D to D. How can construct g

Comment: @S.PitchaiMurugan Let $g(z)=T(f(T(z)))$. Then $g(0)=T(f(T(0)))=T(f(\frac34))=T(\frac34)=0$.